# Should cli commands be installed by default with python libraries?

Tags: python, pip

I am managing Python JIRA package which contains two parts: the jira python module (library) and the jirashell interactive CLI tool.

They were bundled together since forever but CLI tool has an newer requirement IPython and some users complained that [ipython was not installed by default](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/issues/361).

I added it to the list of requirements, and now I got [others complaining](https://github.com/pycontribs/jira/issues/390) that the new requirement is making their use of the library quite hard because is big and problematic to install (also being useless for them because they use only the library).

While I do know how to use optional requirements (extras), I need to make a decision about what gets installed by default (`pip install jira`)

I see these two options:

1. default should install both (big requirements). People that are interested only about getting the library should use `pip install jira[library]` in order to avoid installing the cli requirements.
2. default should install only the library, so `cli` users will be able to use it only if they install it with `pip install jira[cli]`

Please vote the answer that looks as the best approach for you.

Comment: This is almost certainly going to be closed as "primarily opinion based". I would go for the option 3 suggested by grundio. I too use your tools extensively, but I've never seen the value in jira-shell beyond logging you in and I have a simple function to do that.

Answer (score 5):

I like separating entities. JIRA client library could be used anywhere: automating some routine operation, running as a cron script, managing some activities as a backend of some web application and also as a library for command line application.

In my eyes it makes sense to separate them: don't force people so install unnecessary dependencies: why someone needs [click](http://click.pocoo.org/5/) of [ipython](https://ipython.org) on their backend Flask server? Definitely option **#2**. 
By the way, have you considered option **#3**: completely separating them? Separate repositories, separate packages. Would it make sense?
So for JIRA library one would run:

```
pip install jira
```

And for JIRA cli:

```
pip install jira-cli
```

p.s: I'm a user of your library, using it actively at production. Good job! :)

Comment: I will count your answer as #3, "split" which is something I want to avoid at all costs due to extra maintenance burden.  Thanks for the feedback. I think i know which one will win but I will wait few days to rest.

Answer (score 3):

I would personally default to the version that doesn't saddle people with unnecessary dependency hell, your #2. It's not hard to run another command in addition to the obvious one to get the extra thing you need, but it can be very frustrating and opaque to try to figure out that you need to NOT run the obvious command to avoid breakage.

That said, this is pretty subjective and dependent on your users' needs.

Comment: thanks! I will wait to see if there is a trend regarding users options. I am trying to make the decision less subjective. Avoiding change in behaviour for most users counts as an objective reason.

Answer (score 0):

Install both `library` and `cli` by default, allow others to use more complex ways for their use cases.